# How revert a deletion of a folder in git?

Tags: git

I am new to Git so sorry for the easy question.

I committed my java project with git and also committed a few changes. My last change was to delete a bin folder in my project. I pushed this also to my bitbucket account. Now is my question how can I undo this change and retrieve my previous deleted folder. The folder which I delete was named bin.

Thanks

Comment: yes i tried git revert bin but i receive the error that bin is a bad revision

Comment: @AlPhaba You need to specify the commit hash, not the name of the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git revert HEAD
```

It should create a new commit that undoes the change in HEAD.
You should also be given chance to edit message for the new commit.

```
git checkout HEAD path/to/mydirectory
```

should restore your directory, on the other hand..